# How to close tab in Chrome and Edge in fist time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I want to use javascript to close tab in chrome, but I found that the first time I open the chrome browser,and I use javascript code as below.

window.open('','_self');
window.close();

I can't close it, but it works again when I try again. The tab that I opened the browser first time cannot be closed, then I try again and it works again.

What's going on? How can I close tab in first time?

Comment: I try to test your sample JS code with the MS Edge and Google Chrome browsers. I notice that the browser gets launched and gets closed with a flash. so it looks like the code is working as expected. You could see my test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/mMCriLw). I also paste the code into the browser console and it also closes the browser. Let us know if you have more code that could help to reproduce the issue accurately. With your currently posted code, the issue is not reproducible.